# How to use Google Chrome's "--disable-extension-except" command-line switch?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am trying to use the `--disable-extensions-except` switch in the target of a Chrome shortcut I've created in order to have just one particular extension running on startup for debugging purposes, but I am not quite sure how to use the switch effectively.

I have tried:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-extensions-except "extensionsID"
```

and:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-extensions-except "extensionsActualName"
```

but to no avail. I have recently got into actual command-line coding so I am not too sure on all the attributes and such although I am willing to learn more. I know I am missing some syntax.

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure you have the newest Chrome version; that switch is only implemented in Chrome 55 or higher.

Next, and confusingly, it takes a path to the folder containing an *unpacked* extension. Neither an extension ID nor a human-readable name will do it. You'll find your installed Chrome extensions here:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

Inside each folder (named with an extension ID), there is a version folder that has all the interesting stuff. That's the folder path you need. For example, for me, the uBlock Origin extension is unpacked here:

```
C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm\1.10.0_0
```

Once you have that path, pass it to Chrome like this:

```
chrome --disable-extensions-except="C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm\1.10.0_0"
```

Replace `chrome` with the full path to the Chrome EXE, as you have. Note the `=` between the switch name and its value.

Alternatively, if you have an extension you're developing, you can just use the path to the folder that contains its `manifest.json` instead of poking around in Chrome's folders.

You'll get a warning when Chrome starts about running developer-mode extensions, but that's OK.

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple windows.