# Chrome - How to enable a single extension on startup or via terminal? (on mac)

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Is it possible to enable and possibly even configure a Chrome extension on startup of Chrome or by terminal?

Every now and then I need to temporarily disable an extension. I often then forget to re-enable it but it is really important I keep it running as often as possible. I thought that if I can enable the addon through a terminal command then I can run that command on a timer somehow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Google Chrome's "--disable-extension-except" command-line switch?](https://superuser.com/questions/1152864/how-to-use-google-chromes-disable-extension-except-command-line-switch)

Comment: it is not easy to use because one must specify the exact version number.  Also, I tried it and couldn't get it to work!  I have a further complication in that I do in fact need to specify a setting inside the addon on every restart. (but thank you)

Comment: For that complexity I'd suggest writing AutoHotKey script to automate your flow

Comment: thanks @MartheenCahyaPaulo would you know the command to actually change the option of an addon?

Comment: AutoHotKey is meant to replace mouse clicks and keypress, look it up

Comment: ah, it is not available for Mac, I tried Maestro but there just doesn't seem to be a way to select the options (could use mouse coordinates but the order of the extensions could easily change)